# Firefox workaround for position for table-cell element

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, firefox, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have some problems with displaying two peaces of text in one div using bootstrap in Safari. I don't have any problem with webkit browsers.

```
  <div class="row header">
        <div class="title col-lg-11 col-md-11">
            <h2>Some long dont interesing title</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="blackListLink col-lg-1 col-md-1">
            <a href="#">Administrator</a>
        </div>
    </div>

.header {
    display: table;
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-right: 15px;
}

.header > .title, .header > .blackListLink {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    float: none;
}

.header > .title {
    padding-left: 0px;
}

.header > .blackListLink {
    padding-right: 0px;
    text-align: right;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pSvXY/1/)

I try to add position relative to header div. But it doesn't help. Can anyone explain me solution for this problem?

Comment: What exactly is the issue? The fact that the header isn't taking up the full width on larger screens?

Comment: @NicoFerna Yes, I think smth like that because col-lg-11 more narrow in Firefox.